# Issue with fake_useragent json Python 3 not connecting

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

So I have been working with fake_useragent for a web-scraping project. I recently started receiving the following error in Python 3:

```
Error occurred during loading data. Trying to use cache server http://d2g6u4gh6d9rq0.cloudfront.net/browsers/fake_useragent_0.1.10.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jalias/virtualenv/python3.5.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 67, in get
    context=context,
  File "/opt/python/3.5.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/opt/python/3.5.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 466, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/opt/python/3.5.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 484, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/opt/python/3.5.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/opt/python/3.5.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1282, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/opt/python/3.5.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1257, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
  File "/opt/python/3.5.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1198, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/opt/python/3.5.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/opt/python/3.5.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/opt/python/3.5.5/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 576, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jalias/virtualenv/python3.5.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 166, in load
    verify_ssl=verify_ssl,
  File "/home/jalias/virtualenv/python3.5.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 122, in get_browser_versions
    verify_ssl=verify_ssl,
  File "/home/jalias/virtualenv/python3.5.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 84, in get
    raise FakeUserAgentError('Maximum amount of retries reached')
fake_useragent.errors.FakeUserAgentError: Maximum amount of retries reached
```

When I run the script in Python 2, this issue has never popped up. Since this doesn't occur on Python 2, I don't even know how to attempt to find a solution. Does anyone have any information on this they can share?

Comment: Does this issue consistently appear in Python 3 or does it randomly appear? How often do you run the Python 2 script?

Comment: I run both the Python 2 and 3 scripts simultaneously. This error consistently appears at least once (out of 100 instances) every time I run the script in Python 3.